# Can EmberJS and ReactJS be used together

Tags: ember.js, reactjs

I have been looking at both React and Ember, and they seem to be nice frameworks. Is there a way I could get them to work together, or do they have more of a either/or relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Google: [react inside ember](https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ember+and+react+app&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=2z81VYCZJsWE_AXc_YCIAw#safe=active&channel=fs&q=react+inside+ember)

The main reason for doing this kind of thing is performance. React was much faster than Ember, but that has already changed. In the following weeks **glimmer** will be released and it makes Ember just as fast.

You can track progress of the performance improvements here: [isemberfastyet.com](https://www.isemberfastyet.com/)

Comment: Ok nice to know they work together, would it be considered "bad" to use them together?

Comment: Its bad if your project doesn't **need** it and you just do it just for the thrill of it.